# Flux Reactor - simple schedule every hour

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, project-reactor

How can I get the same effect with Reactor instead of java's scheduler?

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
         .scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> counter.set(0) , computeDelay(), computePeriod(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

I tried

```
 Flux
    .interval(Duration.ofMillis(computeDelay()),  Duration.ofMinutes(RESET_PERIOD_MINUTES))
    .doOnNext( counter.set(0))
    .subscribe())
```

But It generates uneccessary Long value. I found some Schedulers in Flux API but while trying to create one I got Disposable object, then I have no idea what should do with it

Comment: maybe you do not really need a `Flux` for this, if it is just flipping a counter?

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, anyway I just tried :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you found both options. the Flux.interval is useful to compose with other operators. it emits longs that represents each tick, because Flux has to emit *something*

Scheduler.schedulePeriodically is the other option, pretty much equivalent to ExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate, except it returns a Disposable rather than a Future of Void. (in both case you'd use that to cancel the work)